# Unable to git pull ubuntu [unable to create symlink Filename too long]

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am unable to pull data from git it is showing me the error :-

```
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/sshpk-conv (File name too long)
```

I tried while editing .git/config file and added

```
longpaths = true
```

still same issue.

Please help me out

Comment: What filesystem are you using? You can get the filesystem of your current work directory by running `mount | grep "^$(df -Pk . | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d ' ') " | cut -f 5 -d ' '`. NTFS for example has a hard limit for filename length.

Comment: I tried with the above command showing no results

Comment: Can you provide a gist with your mounttable by just calling `mount`?

Comment: i don't know how to comment this huge text here. Comment showing text is too long. Where should I put it?

Comment: Use gist for longer outputs: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Daishygoyal/d0b4433f777fcd53cbe0

Comment: Ok you're using ext4, that shouldn't be the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

I have upstream and fork repos. Issue is with develop branch.

This is what happened in my case. 
Git showing one file has been deleted . But actually I didn't delete any file. So I wanted to reset it and take the pull. But it is throwing below error

**unable to create symlink src/config/features.json (File name too long)**

I tried below things but I got same error

```
git rebase -i 
git pull 
git reset --hard HEAD
```

*Solution:*

```
I have committed with the deleted file to my fork on develop branch. 
Then I switched the some other branch let's say release and deleted the issue branch i.e develop.
Then I have deleted develop from my fork as well. 
Now I did checkout to develop branch from upstream repo. and pushed to my fork.
```

Everything is fine now.